# Samesite=Strict cookies are not included in 302 redirects when user clicks link from a different domain

Tags: cookies, http-status-code-302, samesite

1. A customer will link to one of our webpages on their site:  customer.site/links.html
2. A person clicks that link and gets sent to our.site/webapp/handlerequest.aspx?someparam=somevalue
3. The value of `someparam` is set in a cookie with `SameSite=Strict` and then uses a 302 redirect to **another page on the same domain**:

```
Request URL: https://our.site/webapp/handlerequest.aspx?someparam=somevalue
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 
Remote Address: ...
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

cache-control: private
content-length: ...
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
date: ...
location: /webapp/someotheraction
server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
set-cookie: someparam=somevalue; expires=Thu, 17-Mar-2022 14:41:13 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Strict
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
```

The browser does **NOT** include this cookie on the 302 redirect to /webapp/someotheraction.

This only starting happening when we specifically change our code to set this cookie to `SameSite=Strict`.

This occurs in Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and IE (old IE)

Is this on purpose?  Why?  Since we are going from one request on the domain to another request in the same domain, shouldn't the `SameSite=Strict` cookies be included?  Does this have anything to do with the referer policy defaulting to `strict-origin-when-cross-origin`? https://www.w3.org/TR/referrer-policy/ doesn't say anything about cookies

Comment: This also happens on Safari 14 on iOS 14.4

Comment: Check this related question with possibly some useful alternatives to resolve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42216700/1697459

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a cross-site request because the initial navigation was cross-site (from `customer.site` to `our.site`). Strict cookies are never sent on cross-site requests. It doesn't matter that the request gets redirected (in this case, to another URL on `our.site`), just the fact that the user clicked on a cross-site link means the request is cross-site.

As for why this is the case, it's because the origin responsible for initiating the navigation is important in preventing cross-site request forgery ([CSRF](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/csrf)). Imagine if `https://evil.site` had a link to `https://bank.site/transfer-funds` which redirects to `https://bank.site/transact`. We wouldn't want Strict cookies to be send to the `/transact` endpoint after the redirect, even if it was redirected to by the same site, because the initiating origin is cross-site.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer, and I'm not arguing with you, but I think that's silly.  We WANT that cookie to get posted.  I guess we have to use samesite=Lax

Comment: I believe that cookie with SameSite=Strict will still work with a client side redirect instead of using a 302. <meta http-equiv"refresh" content="0; url={local}" />