# How to pass the cookies to third party when samesite=strict which is the default behavior after google chrome version 91

Tags: google-chrome, jsessionid, samesite, third-party-cookies

I have a web application and we are calling a third party to process some data. Once it's done, the third party will redirect back to my application (It's a post redirection). To keep the session, we are using cookies. After the google chrome update, where the default values for samesite=Lax, I've updated our cookies to pass as samesite=None; Secure to overcome this issue. Now after google chrome version 91, this implementation is not working and I'm getting a session expiry issue. Can somebody help to fix this issue for google chrome version 91 and after? I'm using java

Answer (score 0):

The best that we have been able to come up with is a client side meta refresh. When the third party posts back to our application, we have a page filter that will send it to a "refreshMeta" page similar to https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H76.html. This has to happen without calling .getSession() anywhere because that will cause a new session to be created. This causes the page to refresh in the browser and send all original cookies back to the server because its coming from the same domain and a new session wasnt created.

I will say this worked for a while but it looks like there was change in Tomcat that's preventing this approach from working like it did on earlier versions, which is why I'm back looking for another solution.

Comment: This answer has something similar written in .net https://stackoverflow.com/a/64216367/2635670